# Proof about Weierstrass Theorem and limits.

Tags: calculus, proof-writing, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples, fake-proofs

[image]

Okay so this is probably the longest proof I have written. But the idea is simple, and it's pretty much copy paste in the different directions. I'm pretty confident this time around and was wondering if I have any gaps of logic or inaccuracies since we've only started practicing continuity last week..
Also about question a, I just can't seem to find such a function! Can anyone give me a direction?

b.

*We will separate it into cases.*

**Case 1**: $f\left(x\right)\ =\ L$ for every $x ∈ R$.
In this case every point is an extreme point since $f(x)$ is constant.

**Case 2**: There exist $a ∈ R$ such that $f\left(a\right)\ >\ L$.

By definition of limit f at $∞$, we choose $ϵ\ =\ f\left(a\right)\ -\ L$ for which there exist $M_{1}>0$ such that for every $x>M_{1}$ we have $\left|f\left(x\right)-L\right|<f\left(a\right)-L$.

$\ 2L-f\left(a\right)<f\left(x\right)<f\left(a\right)$ ➜ $f\left(x\right)<f\left(a\right)$.

Note that $a≤M_{1}$ since for every $x>M_{1}$ we have $f\left(x\right)<f\left(a\right)$.

By definition of limit f at $-∞$, we choose $ϵ\ =\ f\left(a\right)\ -\ L$ for which there exist $M_{2}<0$ such that for every $x<M_{2}$ we have $\left|f\left(x\right)-L\right|<f\left(a\right)-L$.

$\ 2L-f\left(a\right)<f\left(x\right)<f\left(a\right)$ ➜ $f\left(x\right)<f\left(a\right)$.

Note that $a≥M_{2}$ since for every $x<M_{2}$ we have $f\left(x\right)<f\left(a\right)$.

Since f is continuous in R, in particular, it's continuous on $[M_{2},M_{1}]$. Then by Weierstrass's Theorem there exist $k∈[M_{2},M_{1}]$ such that $f\left(k\right)\ge f\left(x\right)$ for every $x∈[M_{2},M_{1}]$.

Since $f\left(k\right)\ge f\left(a\right)$ in $[M_{2},M_{1}]$ and $f\left(a\right)\ >\ f\left(x\right)$ for every $x$ in $(-∞,M_{2}),(M_{1},∞)$ then $f\left(k\right)\ \ge\ f\left(x\right)$ for every $x∈R$, and by definition an extreme point of $f$.

**Case 3**: There exist $b ∈ R$ such that $f\left(b\right)\ <\ L$.

By definition of limit f at $∞$, we choose $ϵ\ =L\ -\ f\left(b\right)$ for which there exist $M_{1}>0$ such that for every $x>M_{1}$ we have $\left|f\left(x\right)-L\right|<L\ -\ f\left(b\right)$ ➜ $f\left(b\right)\ <\ f\left(x\right)$.

Note that $b≤M_{1}$ since for every $x>M_{1}$ we have $f\left(x\right)>f\left(b\right)$.

By definition of limit f at $-∞$, we choose $ϵ\ =L\ -\ f\left(b\right)$ for which there exist $M_{2}<0$ such that for every $x<M_{2}$ we have $\left|f\left(x\right)-L\right|<L\ -\ f\left(b\right)$ ➜ $f\left(b\right)\ <\ f\left(x\right)$.

Note that $b≥M_{2}$ since for every $x<M_{2}$ we have $f\left(x\right)>f\left(b\right)$.

Since f is continuous in R, in particular, it's continuous on $[M_{2},M_{1}]$. Then by Weierstrass's Theorem there exist $s∈[M_{2},M_{1}]$ such that $f\left(s\right)\le f\left(x\right)$ for every $x∈[M_{2},M_{1}]$.

Since $f\left(s\right)\le f\left(b\right)$ in $[M_{2},M_{1}]$ and $f\left(b\right)\ <\ f\left(x\right)$ for every $x$ in $(-∞,M_{2}),(M_{1},∞)$ then $f\left(s\right)\ \le\ f\left(x\right)$ for every $x∈R$, and by definition an extreme point of $f$.

In conclusion, we have proven f must have an extream point.

Comment: I didn't read your proof (a bit to long). Do you have a theorem that says that continuous function on compact take its minimum and there maximum ? If yes, you can give a much more elegant proof to your exercise, and much much shorter as well.

Comment: Yes we have, I kind of used it in my proof! :) I'd love to hear about a simpler way I could prove it!

Comment: Looks good, just a small typo in the part where you look at the limit at $-\infty$: "... for which there exist $M_1>0$" should be $M_2$. Also we might not be able to choose $M_2>0$ but that is not too important for the rest of the proof. For case 3 you can also refer to 2 as it is more or less the same proof.

Comment: For part (a): Do you know any bounded and strictly increasing (or decreasing if you want) functions? (Maybe draw a picture, then you will probably find one)

Comment: Thanks! I changed it to M2<0 in both cases, and fixed the typo. :) About your question.. I've been playing with Desmos for a while and couldn't figure it out. :(

Comment: For part (a), one example is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function, it is a very useful function.

Comment: for (a), try $f(x)=\tan^{-1}(x)$

Comment: (b): take the sequence of intervals, $[-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}]$, as $n\to 0$ for a shorter proof. Your proof is fine as well.

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost do you mean, on the left end of the interval, $-1/n$? also, for op, that can be rewritten as $[-n,n]$ as $n$ goes to infinity

Comment: @CSquared That's even simpler. xd.

Comment: for some other functions that behave like this for (a), you might be interested in logistic functions. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of working with $g(x):= f(x)-L$, we can suppose WLOG that $L=0$. If  $f=0$, the proof is straightforward. If $f\neq 0$, there is $a\in \mathbb R$ s.t. $f(a)\neq 0$. Suppose WLOG that $f(a)>0$. Since $f(x)\to 0$ when $x\to \pm \infty $, there is $N>0$ s.t. $0\leq f(x)<f(a)$ for all $x\notin [-N,N]$. Since $f$ is continuous, it reach his maximum on $[-N,N]$, which is a maximum on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Nice! As I am a mere begginer, could you explain in what scenarios I can and can't use WLOG?

Comment: @MathCurious: it depend on the context. Here you can suppose $L=0$, because if you don't, then you can prove that $g(x)=f(x)-L$ has an extremum, and $g$ is such that $\lim_{x\to \pm\infty }g(x)=0$ (which is equivalent to prove that $f$ has an extremum). And in the second case, I can suppose WLOG that $f(a)>0$ because, if $f(a)<0$, the strategy of the proof is the same (and you'll have a minimum instead of a maximum).

Answer (score 0):

Hint. For question (a), try to modify the following function
$$
g(x)=\frac{x}{1+|x|}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the response! I will surely try. :)

Comment: @MathCurious: A simpler example would be $f(x)=\arctan(x)$ or $f(x)=x^{1/3}$.

Comment: How would I prove that arctan(x) for example doesn't have an extreme point? I know that by Weierstrass a function is bounded on a closed interval, but I'm not sure we quiet focused on what happens in the closed interval..

Comment: @MathCurious $arctan(x)$ is a monotone increasing function, so $-\frac{\pi}{2} \lt f(x)\lt f(x+\epsilon) \lt \frac{\pi}{2}$. This is for every $x$.

Comment: @MathCurious i can’t ever keep this straight in my head, but inverse tangent has no critical points on the real line. i believe that means it has no extremum, since critical points are extremums. if someone could verify my claim, that would be great

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost wouldn’t you need to provide a function that has no critical points but still has an extremum?

Comment: @CSquared I misread that. Sorry. You are correct, a function defined on a closed domain attains its maximum or minimum values either on the end point or at points in the closed interval where its derivetive is 0.

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost no worries. thanks for checking.